# MinMax algorithm implementation in map-reduce paradigm

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, scoring, minmax

I have some data in Hbase tables ( few billions). I have to process them to score the stored documents. What are the possible algorithms that can be implemented and applied in mapreduce paradigm.

I have tried to deploy MinMax algorithm but due to its requirement, all data is shifted to single node in reducer phase (to find min and max value). Due to that reason, GC overhead limit is read that was quite expected as single node could not have so much memory to process all data in single go.

Is there any other option available for hbase document ranking (scoring) in mapreduce paradigm ?

Comment: Have you considered using a different framework such as Spark?

Comment: No, I have not ?